# Laravel 7 + Vue - api not defined - Unable to display task-post in vue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-7

I am creating a task crm in vue and Laravel 7 which has a form to upload multiple images. I am in the testing phase and I cannot get my `AllTask.vue` to display. I have a `CreateTask.vue` form component which is displaying as expected but the `AllTasks.vue` component does not. In the console I am getting the error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: api is not defined
```

Being new to Laravel and Vue, I am unclear how to define my api. First I had my controllers located in an API folder within the controllers folder and called them in my `api.php` file as follows:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/task', function (Request $request) {
     return $request->task();
 });

Route::apiResources(['user' => 'API\UserController']);
Route::apiResources(['task' => 'API\TaskController']);
```

That threw the api not defined error so I commented out the part of the task in this call and moved my controllers out of the API folder and into the regular controllers folder.

After clearing the cache and re-compiling the app, I am left with the same error in the console. I hope someone can orient me here as I am completely lost.
Here is the code I have so far:

TaskController.php

```
public function getAllTasks()
    {
        $tasks = Task::with('task_images')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        return response()->json(['error' => false, 'data' => $tasks]);
    }


public function createTask(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $task_name = $request->task_name;
        $task_priority = $request->task_priority;
        $task_assigned_to = $request->task_assigned_to;
        $task_assigned_by = $request->task_assigned_by;
        $task_description = $request->task_description;
        $task_to_be_completed_date = $request->task_to_be_completed_date;
        $task_status = $request->task_status;
        $task_notes = $request->task_notes;
        $task_finished = $request->task_finished;
        $task_image_description = $request->task_image_description;
        $task_image_id = $request->task_image_id;
        $images = $request->images;

        $task = Task::create([
            'task_name' => $task_name,
            'task_priority' => $task_priority,
            'task_assigned_to' => $task_assigned_to,
            'task_assigned_by' => $task_assigned_by,
            'task_description' => $task_description,
            'task_to_be_completed_date' => $task_to_be_completed_date,
            'task_status' => $task_status,
            'task_notes' => $task_notes,
            'task_finished' => $task_finished,
            'task_image_description' => $task_image_description,
            'task_image_id' => $task_image_id,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ]);

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imagePath = Storage::disk('uploads')->put($user->id . '/tasks', $image);
            TaskImage::create([
                'task_image_description' => $task_image_description,
                'task_image_path' => '/uploads/' . $imagePath,
                'task_id' => $task->id
            ]);
        }
        return response()->json(['error' => false, 'data' => $task]);
    }
```

app.js

```
require("./bootstrap");
window.Vue = require("vue");

import store from "./store/index";
import ElementUI from "element-ui";
import "element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css";

Vue.use(ElementUI);

import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";
import moment from "moment";
window.Form = Form;
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
import VueProgressBar from "vue-progressbar";
Vue.use(VueProgressBar, {
    color: "rgb(143, 255, 199)",
    failedColor: "red",
    height: "6px"
});
import Swal from "sweetalert2";
// const Swal = require('sweetalert2')
window.Swal = Swal;
const toast = Swal.mixin({
    toast: true,
    position: "top-end",
    showConfirmButton: false,
    timer: 3000,
    timerProgressBar: true,
    onOpen: toast => {
        toast.addEventListener("mouseenter", Swal.stopTimer);
        toast.addEventListener("mouseleave", Swal.resumeTimer);
    }
});
window.toast = toast;
let routes = [
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        component: require("./components/Dashboard.vue").default
    },
    {
        path: "/developer",
        component: require("./components/Developer.vue").default
    },
    {
        path: "/profile",
        component: require("./components/Profile.vue").default
    },
    {
        path: "/users",
        component: require("./components/Users.vue").default
    },
    {
        path: "/tasks",
        component: require("./components/Tasks.vue").default
    }
];
const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
});
Vue.filter("upText", function(text) {
    return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
});
Vue.filter("myDate", function(created_date) {
    return moment(created_date).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
});

window.Fire_event = new Vue();
Vue.component(
    "example-component",
    require("./components/ExampleComponent.vue").default
);

Vue.component(
    "dashboard-component",
    require("./components/Dashboard.vue").default
);

Vue.component(
    "passport-clients",
    require("./components/passport/Clients.vue").default
);

Vue.component(
    "passport-authorized-clients",
    require("./components/passport/AuthorizedClients.vue").default
);

Vue.component(
    "passport-personal-access-tokens",
    require("./components/passport/PersonalAccessTokens.vue").default
);

Vue.component("create-task", require("./components/CreateTask.vue").default);

Vue.component("all-tasks", require("./components/AllTasks.vue").default);

const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    store
});
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('{path}', "HomeController@index")->where('path', '([A-z\d/\/_.]+)?');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix' => 'task'], function () {
    Route::get('get_all', 'TaskController@getAllTasks')->name('fetch_all');
    Route::post('create_task', 'TaskController@createTask')->name('create_task');
});
```

If I have missed anything or you would like to see more information that I may have missed, please let me know and I will gladly edit my query. Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT**
AllTasks.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" v-for="(task, i) in tasks" :key="i">
      <div class="card mt-4">
        <img
          v-if="task.task_images.length"
          class="card-img-top"
          :src="task.task_images[0].task_image_path"
          alt
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">
            <strong>{{ task.task_name }}</strong>
          </p>
          <br />
          {{ truncateText(task.task_description) }}
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success m-2" @click="viewTask(i)">View Task</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <el-dialog v-if="currentTask" :visible.sync="taskDialogVisible" width="40%">
      <span>
        <h3>{{ currentTask.task_name }}</h3>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6" v-for="(img, i) in currentTask.task_images" :key="i">
            <img :src="img.task_image_path" class="img-thumbnail" alt />
          </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h5>Assigned To</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_assigned_to }}</p>
        <h5>Assigned By</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_assigned_by }}</p>
        <h5>Due</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_to_be_completed_date }}</p>
        <h5>Notes</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_notes }}</p>
        <h5>Priority</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_priority }}</p>
        <h5>Status</h5>
        <p>{{ currentTask.task_status }}</p>
      </span>
      <span slot="footer" class="dialog-footer">
        <el-button type="primary" @click="taskDialogVisible = false">Okay</el-button>
      </span>
    </el-dialog>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  name: "all-tasks",
  data() {
    return {
      taskDialogVisible: false,
      currentTask: "",
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["tasks"]),
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getAllTasks");
  },
  methods: {
    truncateText(text) {
      if (text.length > 24) {
        return `${text.substr(0, 24)}...`;
      }
      return text;
    },
    viewTask(taskIndex) {
      const task = this.tasks[taskIndex];
      this.currentTask = task;
      this.taskDialogVisible = true;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

In Resources/js/store/index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        tasks: []
    },
    actions: {
        async getAllTasks({ commit }) {
            return commit("setTasks", await api.get("/task/get_all"));
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        setTasks(state, response) {
            state.tasks = response.data.data;
        }
    },
    strict: debug
});
```

**EDIT #2**
after adding the following to bootstrap.js

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
window.api = window.axios;

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

The `api is not defined` error went away but was replaced with:

```
TypeError: api.task is not a function
```

I have isolated where this is located. In CrateTask.vue I have this line:

```
api.task("/task/create_task", formData, {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        })
```

The problem (my problem) is I am a noob and don't know how to resolve it. Again, Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I'm guessing you are calling the API from AllTasks component. Would you mind sharing that part as well?

Comment: Hello Hatef. Thank you. I have edited the question to include both AllTasks.vue and resources/js/store/index.js. I hope it sheds light on what I am missing. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! What is `api` in this line? `return commit("setTasks", await api.get("/task/get_all"));` - is it a global variable?

Comment: Thank you Hatef. This was my question as I was following a tutorial. I asked the author but he hasn't replied.

Comment: Do you have a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for asking. The link is: https://medium.com/js-dojo/build-a-simple-blog-with-multiple-image-upload-using-laravel-vue-5517de920796 
I modified it to suit my own needs as I am not doing a blog but rather a task list application that requires mulitple image uploads.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/MartinsOnuoha/BlogCafe/blob/master/resources/js/bootstrap.js - `api` is basically the `axios` client. Please make sure you have it in your `bootstrap.js`

Comment: Thank you Hatef. That cleared the error but of course another error took its place. Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: api.task is not a function" : I will look into this to see if I can trace its origins. If you can shed some light, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks again. It's getting me closer.

Comment: In one of the comments for that article he says he sets it up in `bootstrap` like this: `const api = axios.create({ baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/', timeout: 1000, headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'} });`

Comment: I strongly suggest that you make a course to learn the basics of thecnologies you are working. Remember that in programming, sometimes works but it's not right. Not knowing what your code does can be very dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Task is not a method of axios. Probably, you need to call api.get to reach your laravel controller route. Try to always look up for the documentation before reaching here.

Take a look at the docs [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)